# VueJS - Unable to display image and message when the id is used, which is coming from the API

Tags: image, vue.js

I am trying to do something like this:

```js
              <vx-card>
                 <div class="header">
                   <div class="left">
                     <img :src="'./img/info_' + infos.id + '_logo.png'" alt=""/>       
                     <p>{{infos.name}}</p>
                      <vs-button @click="checkIn($event, infos.id.toString())" <vs-button>
                   </div>
                 <div class="right">
                       {{message.recent}}       
                 </div>
               </div>
              </vx-card>
    
    <script>
    infos: [],
    mes: []
    ...
    created () {
      this.$http.get('/infos')                                       
        .then((response) => { this.infos = response.data })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
      
    const id = this.infos.id.toString()      
      this.$http.get('/messages/' + id+ '/tick')                      
        .then((response) => { this.message = response.data })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
    },
    methods: {
      checkIn (event, id) {
        this.$http.get('/payment/'+ id +'/tick')
          .then((response) => { this.pay = 'Success' })
          .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Here is my /infos response:

```
[
        ...

      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Highway",
        "price": "High",
        "min": "785",
        "max": "1856",
        "tag": null,
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Lowway",
        "price": "low",
        "min": "685",
        "max": "1956",
        "tag": null,
      } 

      ...

    ]
```

As you can see my code, i am trying use the id that is coming from the API. But here i am not able to get three things and they are:

1. Image is broken, even though the path is proper, here the id is not recognised by it.
2. Nothing is displaying in {{message.recent}}, here again the id to the url says undefined.
3. In button i am unable to use the infos.id, please do help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, your infos response seems to be an array of objects.
SO in that case you need to loop over the array to get single object and from that object you can get the id.

If you try to to do `infos.id` it will be undefined. as id doesn't exist in that array. It exists only inside the object in array.

You can either use `infos[0].id` or use a for loop to iterate.

eg: `const id = this.infos[0].id.toString()`

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me how to concatenate in image

Comment: You can try `<img :src="'./img/info_' + infos[0].id + '_logo.png'" alt=""/> `. You can add a If check to make sure the code is not breaking when there are no infos. 
eg: `<img v-if="infos[0]"  :src="'./img/info_' + infos[0].id + '_logo.png'" alt=""/> `

Comment: can you help me understand what didnt work? you mean infos[0].id didnt work?

Comment: Yes in the image infos[0].id did not work

Comment: Okay. Can you just try to print the value of infos[0].id in your template. something like `<div> {{ infos[0].id }} </div>` just to verify that the value is picking up or not.
If value is present then we'll have to check if the path is right or is binding image is picking up correctly

Answer (score 1):

Add a `v-if="infos"` to render the template when you have the information from api.

```
  <vx-card v-if="infos">
```

Comment: Yeah tried it, still not able to get rid of those three issues

Comment: Should i change anything in my code or is it fine ?

Comment: Please paste the api structure response from `/infos` and `'/messages/' + id+ '/tick'`

Comment: Please check my question, the /messages/ +id+/tick gives id undefined error. So i want to know whether i have done it in a right way

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem here in the asynchronous flow of the create hook. You have two requests that are building on each other but the second one is not waiting for the first one. This way you access data that you probably don't have yet (`const id = this.infos.id.toString`).

So you have to chain the responses. You can learn something about promise chaining with then [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) or use async / await

```
async create() {
  try {
    const infoResponse = await this.$http.get('/infos')
    this.infos = infoResponse.data

    const id = this.infos.id.toString()
    const messageResponse = await this.$http.get('/messages/' + id+ '/tick')                      
    this.message = messageResponse.data
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

As mentioned before, you should still hide the component by `v-if` as long as you have not received the data yet.